# How to insert current date into subject line of email SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, email, getdate

I have a stored procedure which generates a certain table which I need to email my email list with a specific subject line with the current date. I used the GETDATE() function but I'm getting an error. Below is my code:

```
    if exists (select * from #Notify)
    begin

        declare
            @TableHtml varchar(max);

        exec GetTableHtml #Notify, @TableHtml = @TableHtml output;

            declare
                @FromName varchar(128) = 'AB',
                @FromEmail varchar(128) = 'ab@xy.com',
                @ToEmailListName varchar(max) = 'SomeList',
                @SubjectTxt varchar(max) = 'Some text' + cast(GETDATE() as date),
                @BodyTxt varchar(max) = 'Body content:<br><br>' + @TableHtml + '
                <br><br>Thanks.';

            exec StartSendEmail
                @FromName = @FromName,
                @FromEmail = @FromEmail,
                @ToEmailListName = @ToEmailListName,
                @SubjectTxt = @SubjectTxt,
                @BodyTxt = @BodyTxt;

    end
```

The error I'm getting:
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you need to convert the date to `varchar` so that `+` is treated as concatenation, not addition, or use the `CONCAT()` function if you are on SQL Server 2012 onward.

```
@SubjectTxt varchar(max) = 'Some text' + cast(cast(GETDATE() as date) as varchar(64)),
```

Or more simply...

```
@SubjectTxt varchar(max) = 'Some text' + convert(varchar(10),GETDATE(),101),
```

This also applies to `INT`, `DECIMAL`, and other datatypes. Here's why... `SELECT GETDATE() + 1` doesn't add the number 1 to the end of the date, it literally adds a day. (Don't use this though, use `DATEADD`)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CONCAT`:

```
DECLARE @SubjectTxt varchar(max) = CONCAT('Some text ', cast(GETDATE() as date))
SELECT @SubjectTxt;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/KMB60989)**

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max)
SET @s = 'Data for '+CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),GETDATE(),107)


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@recipients=@email,
@body= @msg,
@body_format = 'HTML',
@subject = @s
@profile_name = 'testprofile'
```